# Area of Polar curve loops. From Edwards Treatise on the Integral Calculus,p435,Qu49

Tags: calculus

Show that the curve

$$
r = a(\sqrt{3}/2+\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}))
$$
has three loops, whose areas are
$$
a^2(\frac{5\pi}{4}+2\sqrt{3})
$$

$$
a^2(\frac{5\pi}{6}-\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{4})
$$
$$
a^2(\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4})
$$
respectively.
Drawing this in Python shows
[image]
Firstly, I can only see 2 loops and not three. An inner one and an outer one. The plot exhibits symmetry about the x-axis. Can anyone offer some guidance on where I have gone wrong and how areas may be be calculated.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r+%3D+sqrt3%2F2%2Bcos%28theta%2F2%29) shows $3$ loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you know how to compute the area of a region bounded by a curve given in polar coordinates, so that your problem just relates to figuring out where the loops are, and how they relate to one another. Here's a plot from Wolfram Alpha (with $a=1$):
[image]

One thing that's not clear to me from the question is whether the areas bounded by the loops are supposed to be disjoint.  Does the area of the big loop include the area areas of the smaller loop, or is it supposed to be the area inside the loop and outside the medium loop?  I have the same question about the medium loop and the small loop.  Once you figure out the areas and compare them to the answers in the book, you'll be able to answer these questions.

The function is periodic with period $4\pi$, so we only consider $0\leq\theta\leq4\pi.$  Think of a point travelling on the curve as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $4\pi$.  It starts on the positive $x$-axis, travels counterclockwise till it reaches the origin, makes the small, then completes the middle loop, and finally returns to where it started, completing the big loop.

So, do the small loop first.  The point passes through the origin when $\cos(\frac\theta2)=-\frac{\sqrt3}2$ that is, when $\theta = \frac{5\pi}3$ and when $\theta=\frac{7\pi}3$.  So the area of the small loop is$$\frac12\int_{5\pi/3}^{7\pi/3}a^2\left(\cos\frac\theta2\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta=a^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{3\sqrt3}4\right)$$ in agreement with the third area listed in the text.

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Firstly, I have to revisit my Python script and see why I didn't show 3 loops as you have kindly demonstrated using Wolfram ! Sort of get it from there but I think it is seeking revisiitng 'r= 0 ' as theta transverse a range ? Is the range 2pi,4pi, ... ?

Comment: @Callie12 No, as I said, the range is $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$.  Since $\cos\theta$ has period $2\pi$, $\cos\frac\theta2$ has period $4\pi$.

Comment: @Callie12 There was a typo in my last comment.  The domain  is $0\leq\theta\leq \color{red}{4}\pi$.  I hope that was clear from the second sentence.  My apologies. if this confused you.